# Nuxt Firestore Pagination/Pull more documents while scrolling using fetch

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, fetch, nuxt.js

This is my current nuxt fetch on my index.vue page.

```
async fetch() {
const response = this.$fireStore
  .collection('recipes')
  .where('publish', '==', true)
  .orderBy('updated', 'desc')
  .limit(10)

try {
  await response.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    const lastVisible = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.size - 1]
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {  
      this.articles.push({
           doc.data()
      }) 
    })
  })
} catch (e) {
  console.log('There is some error: ' + e)
  return
}  
console.log('Success')}
```

I have a method in which it is expected to recall $fetch when it reaches end of page.

```
 methods: {
    fetchMorePosts{
      if (iAmAboutToReachEnd) {            
          this.$fetch()
        }
   }        
  },
```

now in my next fetch I want to pass additional parameter to the query startAfter(lastVisible)

how can I achieve this?

I tried to do this but I get error saying response defined but not getting used(inside if block). Also another error response undefined outside if block.

```
 async fetch() {
 if (this.lastVisible === null){
 const response = this.$fireStore
  .collection('recipes')
  .where('publish', '==', true)
  .orderBy('updated', 'desc')
  .limit(10)
} else {
    const response = this.$fireStore
  .collection('recipes')
  .where('publish', '==', true)
  .orderBy('updated', 'desc')
  .startAfter(this.lastVisible)
 .limit(10)
}     


   try {
  await response.get().then((querySnapshot) => { same code goes here })}
```

Data property for reference :

```
 data() {
    return {
      lastVisible: null,
      articles: []
    }
  }
```

Comment: ok I have found a way, but definitely I am not liking that approach :(.  I was initially trying cater const response inside if statement, now i have included entire code (try and catch blocks) inside the if statement. so whole code is repeated twice but with one line changed that is adding startAfter() in the else block.

Comment: ok I have found a way, but definitely I am not liking that approach :(.  I was initially trying cater const response inside if statement, now i have included entire code (try and catch blocks) inside the if statement. so whole code is repeated twice but with one line changed that is adding startAfter() in the else block.